# VBA Excel 2007 - Merge values in a string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string who looks like this:

```
a -> 80
b -> 40
c -> 20
a -> 10
```

What I'd like to know is if it's possible to have this output:

```
a -> 80 + 10 = 90
b -> 40
c -> 10
```

The code would find the values that are repeated and then "merge" the numbers who are next to it. It's a string, so I assume it's not possible to do the calculation, but if there's a way to do the a -> 80 + 10 it would be also fine (and save me a lot of time).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ummm... not quite sure what you mean, but if the letters represent columns, what you could do is scroll to the furthers down cell, so for example is you have 10 cells with numbers in column a and 15 in column b and 17 in column c you'd scroll down one cell past 17, and put this formula: `=SUM(C1:C17)` in the formula bar,  (its c1 to c17 because in my example to you there were 16 used cells in colujmn c, and that was the most used cells in one column) and then u drage that left and right so basically it will sum each column..